# programming Spring MVC controller and jsp for HttpDelete

Tags: java, spring, jsp, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to delete an entity on a page via a delete link (a href) or delete button (form). I am using delete button since a link calls for a "GET" instead of a "POST"

This is the JSP code which intends on doing that:

```
<td><form:form method="DELETE" action="/client/invoices/${invoice.id}"><input type="submit" value="delete"></form:form></td>
```

The resulting html is this:

```
<td><form id="command" action="/client/invoices/9" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE"/><input type="submit" value="delete"></form></td>
```

So, I'm pretty happy. It has _method which indicates that it is a DELETE action. Here is my controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public String delete(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page, @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false) Integer size, Model uiModel) {
        invoiceServiceHibernate.removeInvoice(id);
        return "redirect:/invoices";
}
```

So, what happens is that this method is not called. I have another method which does a POST to create an invoice and clicking the delete button instead created an invoice. My guess is that the controller looks at the servlet as a POST request and uses the first method which handles a POST request which in this case is to create a new invoice.

I try to make this "RESTful" so I want this to be `/invoice/id` and using `POST, PUT, DELETE, GET` but I am not sure how to code that in the controller using Spring MVC.

I am able to get this to work by appending "verbs" such as `/invoices/id/delete` and setting up the controller as

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Note, the RequestMethod.POST but since the map values explicitly have `/id/delete`, it does not use the default POST which is mapped to `/invoices` and `/invoices/id`.

I hope I am clear. If anyone have any suggestions or sample code (strongly preffered), I would appreciate it. I've read these SO links for references:
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523843/how-do-you-send-a-request-with-the-delete-http-verb)
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016258/the-restful-flow)
[Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133564/spring-mvc-controller-problem-with-delete)

Comment: Am facing the same problem. I hav added the filter too.but sill the delete method got converted to POST. Can u help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you set the [HiddenHttpMethodFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/HiddenHttpMethodFilter.html) in your web.xml? That filter converts posted method parameters into HTTP methods and allows support for method conversion in the Spring MVC form tags.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>servletName</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Am facing the same problem. I hav added the filter too.but sill the delete method got converted to POST. Can u help

Answer (score 2):

Here is the equivalent in Java Config (requires Servlet API 3.0+)

```
    servletContext
        .addFilter("HiddenHttpMethodFilter", HiddenHttpMethodFilter.class)
        .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "<your desired mapping here>");
```